# How to identify which sensor I am communicating with Bluetooth LE?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm getting started on an iOS Bluetooth LE project.  I'm trying to find out if there a standard way to figure out which sensor I am communicating with.  My iOS app is a central, and there could be multiple instances of the sensor (peripheral) nearby.  Say it's a temperature sensor and there are 3 sensors in a box and I need to know which is which. (Top, middle, bottom as a simple example.)

Traditional Bluetooth would use a 'pairing' button or enter a key code.  In BLE, it seems many sensors are small and won't have buttons or interfaces.  Is there an established way to determine which sensor is which?  Or do I have to rely on having a way for the user to send some fixed info from the sensor to identify it?

thx

Answer (score 0):

Just have each sensor advertise a specific service to identify which one is which. Ensure you place the service in it's advertisement data, otherwise you'll have to connect and discover which one is which. Or you could also consider naming each device differently (in the case that they each have the same services and characteristics).